# Elastic search latest data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search.

I have Type and document ex: articles, each article have time-stamp for version and category ID.

There are duplicate records with unique version and same category ID.

My problem is how to get list of latest article for given Category ID

> Ex: article name: java, category id:1,  version:  123345
>
> Ex: article name: java, category id:1,  version:  123346
>
> Ex: article name: java, category id:1,  version:  123347
>
> Ex: article name: mysql, category id:1,  version:  123345
>
> Ex: article name: mysql, category id:1,  version:  123346
>
> Ex: article name: mysql, category id:1,  version:  123347

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the straight search query is a nested aggregation. The straight search as suggested by Jay is great but it will return all 6 documents instead of 2...just the latest versions. If your goal is to only see the latest you could try the following.

Here I am simply combining the [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and the [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregations. This aggregation combination will give you only the latest of each specific name (java vs mysql) for the category_id 1.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{ "term": {"category_id": 1 }}]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top-versions": {
      "terms": { "field": "name"},
      "aggs": {
        "top_match": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{ "version": {"order": "desc"}}],
            "_source": { "include": ["name","_id"]},
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I just forget to mention that, I am looking in java api.

Comment: Ok. You can still do this query in the java api.

Comment: Current link to "Top hits aggregation" in ElasticSearch 8.2: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "version" field is a timestamp, try this query

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "category_id": 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort" : [
        { "version" : {"order" : "desc" } }
    ]
}
```